# How to remove all symbols inside brackets from string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string "Some words, some other words (words in brackets)"

How can I completely remove words in brackets with brackets too, to get "Some words, some other words " string as result?

I'm newbie for regexp but I promise to learn to they works )

Thank for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
# irb
irb(main):001:0> x = "Some words, some other words (words in brackets)"
=> "Some words, some other words (words in brackets)"
irb(main):002:0> x.gsub(/\(.*?\)/, '')
=> "Some words, some other words "
```

Comment: This Regex has a flaw as it will remove to much of the string if there is more than one pair of brackets.

Comment: @Daandi Which can be mitigated by using the Regex `/\(.*?\)/`, which will tell it to stop matching the instant it hits the first end bracket. It gets more complicated for nested brackets though... better to start parsing it character-by-character if that happens. It can be done with recursive regex, but it's tricky. I asked a question about it awhile back: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9756884/303940

Comment: Daandi is more than correct. The answer has been edited to reflect that important distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the greedyness of the "*" if there is more than on pair of brackets everything within will be deleted:

```
s = "Some words, some other words (words in brackets) some text and more ( text in brackets)"
=> "Some words, some other words (words in brackets) some text and more ( text in brackets)" 

ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > s.gsub(/\(.*\)/, '')
=> "Some words, some other words "
```

A more stable solution would be:

```
/\(.*?\)/
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :008 > s.gsub(/\(.*?\)/, '')
=> "Some words, some other words  some text and more "
```

Leaving the text between groups of brackets intact.

Answer (score 0):

[String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
>>  "Some words, some other words (words in brackets)"[/(.*)\(/, 1] 
    #=> "Some words, some other words "
```

The regexp means: group everything `(.*)` before the first open bracket `\(`, and the argument `1` means: take the first group.

If you need to match also the closed bracket you can use `/(.*)\(.*\)/`, but this will return `nil` if the string does not contain one of the brackets.

`/(.*)(\(.*\))?/` matches also strings which not contain brackets.